# Why does VSC throw syntax errors with this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I do not simply ask for advice on why something isn't working as intended, but as to why VSC or my linter (ProSpector) seems to think it is wrong. I'm a little stuck and after reverting my code back to how it used to be, it seems to still show it as an error.

```
@cmd.add_command(name='addgroup', aliases=['ag',])
def add_group(group):
  if group in mods:
    print(f'{color["blue"]}{group}{color["red"]} is a duplicate. Try something different.{color["reset"]}')
  else:
    mods[group] = []
```

Something is wrong with this code, and it is not my objects, as they are all defined. This is some kind of syntax error:
[image: ScreenShot of error]

Any help is greatly appreciated because I'm so unsure of the issue. In all honesty, it might be VSC messing up, because my code still runs fine, but I really am not sure.

Comment: And you have verified that there is no syntax error or other error when actually running the code?

Comment: Yes, check my below answer to the issue. Quite an odd one this one was.

Comment: No images of code please.

Comment: It's an image of the error my friend. Read the post please.

Answer (score 0):

The weirdest part about this issue is that it seemingly has no cause. I have found a fix for it while writing this question and will list it below:

- Cut Code
- Paste Code

[image: Weird but I'm not complaining]

Done. Why does this fix this weird persistent error that wouldn't go away when I retype code? I have no clue, but the cut and paste method works, so there we go.